# display result of Search Twitter4j in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, twitter4j

Im using Twitter4j to get tweets with a hashtag  , I succeeded to display result in console , but not in list view

```
         list = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            listtwitt.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
            TwitAsyncTask twitAsync = new TwitAsyncTask();
            twitAsync.execute();


}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class TwitAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private ProgressDialog progressDialo;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         progressDialo = ProgressDialog.show(SocialNetwork.this, "", "En cours...");
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         final Query query = new Query();
            query.setQuery("%23morocco");
         QueryResult result;
        try {
            result = twitter.search(query);
             for (twitter4j.Status status : result.getTweets()) {
                        k++;
                        String stat = "@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText() +":"+status.getGeoLocation() +":"+status.getCreatedAt();
                        SocialNetwork.list.add(stat);
                         System.out.println(stat);

                 }
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

                    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialo.dismiss();
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        arrayAdapter.addAll(SocialNetwork.list);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

I tested a random string array statically and listview is displayed (listview works well) , I think the problem is in the thread, but I do not exactly know where

Comment: Have you checked (breakpoint) what you get in the QueryResult after the 'search(query)' ? Does it return anything?

Comment: Query result returns a list of tweets that are displayed in console, but the list is empty

Comment: Change your code. First do the "arrayadapter" thing.
Then run the thread. inside the thread put the listtwit.add("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText() +":"+status.getGeoLocation() +":"+status.getCreatedAt())

What I think is happening is that your adding your arraylist to the listview before the response from twitter search query arrives.

Comment: I tried to do  list.add ("test") instead of list.add ("@ ...") it does not work

Comment: You tried to add the elements directly onto the listview?

-> Initialize List view
-> Run Thread
-- Inside Thread put the ListView.add(..).
. You don't need an array for that example.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you've just updated?

Comment: I changed Thread to TwitAsyncTask , same result here

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but I can't seem to find any errors in your current edited code. The only thing I would recommend is to try and breakpoint on PostExecute and do a foreach insertion on the array adapter to make sure it is really inserting correctly and checking afterwards the array adapter object (bpoint).

Also if you are calling .addAll() on the adapter, if you aren't overriding the array adapter, you don't need to call notifydatasetchange because addAll already does that.

try setting the adapter again to the list on PostExec just to see if adapter is getting the new elements